# In VBA Excel through ADO SQL, How may I refer to a record "only once" and link it to another avoiding the same record to be recalled?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado, adodb

I have a table with 3 fields: 
(the quantity are positive and negative) 
TAB_A
ID | quantity | Related_ID 
1          100             *? (It is 2 and it is correct)
2         -100            (nothing)
3         100             *? (It is 2 but it should be 4)
4         -100            (nothing)

and the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE Table_A AS ta LEFT JOIN Table_A AS tb ON ta.[quantity] = -tb.[quantity] 
SET ta.Related_ID = tb.[ID] 
WHERE ta.[quantity] > 0 AND tb.[Quantity] < 0
```

I would like to add to the query a part that recognizes the ID already used and won't use them a second time.

Comment: I know other ways to accomplish the task as parse all the record through ado recordset but it would take ages.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help, depending on whether all your data is like the sample you posted.

```
query from question
and tb.id = 
(select min(id)
from table_a
where id > ta.id)
```

The syntax might not be 100% correct but the logic should be ok.  Test this by changing your update query to a select query and look at the results.

Comment: This solution is in line with my question but I do not think if it is able to cover all the cases. The initial results can be also listed as follow:   1.  -100  2. -90  3. -100  4. 100  5. 90  6. 100  The quantity could be listed in any order randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is in line with my question but I do not think if it is able to cover all the cases. The initial results can be also listed as follow:

1. -100
2. -90
3. -100
4. 100
5. 90
6. 100

The quantity could be listed in any order randomly.